# Qt - Event listener for tree widget item click?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I catch the click event of a tree widget item ?

For button click event, there is

```
public slots:
    void on_someBtn_clicked();
```

Is there similiar syntax to handle tree widget item click ?

Comment: Do not mix terminology together, events are not slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via [QTreeWidget::itemClicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked) signal.

All you need to do is:

*Create a slot*

```
public slots:
    void on_treewidget_clicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column);
```

*... and connect it to the appropriate signal:*

```
connect(ui.tree, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
        this,    SLOT(on_treewidget_clicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)));
```